# Where does the compiler for source code to MSIL resides in .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a question regarding .NET Framework: Where does the compiler for source code to MSIL reside? Is it at CLR itself or any other layer? Also, please give me very small (yet enough) illustration for the .NET Framework.

[[image: .NET FRAMEWORK[1]]

Answer (score 5):

Here's a quick flowchart (notations not followed) that will clarify most of it.

[image]

C# or VB compilers are **just the tools** which convert your code (managed) to IL which CLR understands. These tools work when you compile using Visual Studio.

JIT (JIT compilation) is one of the features of CLR which, at run-time, converts IL code to machine code which is executed finally. This is why sometimes, at a high-level, we say CLR does IL-to-Machine code conversion.

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language);

A CIL assembly and instructions are generated by **either a compiler or a utility called the IL Assembler (ILAsm)** that is **shipped with the execution environment**.

Assembled CIL can also be disassembled into code again using the IL Disassembler (ILDASM). There are other tools such as .NET Reflector that can decompile CIL into a high-level language (e. g. C# or Visual Basic). This makes CIL a very easy target for reverse engineering. This trait is shared with Java bytecode. However, there are tools that can obfuscate the code, and do it so that the code cannot be easily readable but still be runnable.

Comment: Good info. Question by OP is whether C# compiler is part of .NET CLR?