# What happens when i press the run button in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I only know html  and css.

And now I need to study c#

Can someone please explain what happens when i click the run button on my visual studio?

When does translating the souce code into machine code happens?

when does visual studio create an .exe?

Does this executable is already MSIL code already?

I already read some introduction of c#. But still i dont understand a thing.

I only need idea on how things works.

Thank you so much.

Comment: You have to do your homework and research, and ask specific questions. I have included an answer that might help you...

Answer (score 1):

When you press the run button, it compiles and build the assemblies and executable file from the source code.

You can find your exe in the bin folder.

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34281411/where-does-the-compiler-for-source-code-to-msil-resides-in-net-framework)